# Ошибка ValueError: could not convert string to float: '77,59'

Tags: python, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup

Как исправить? Ошибка возникает когда я хочу превратить элемент из списка в число.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['convert'])
def cmd_convert(message):
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    currency = []
    for figures in soup.select('span.inline-stocks__value_inner'):
        currency.append(figures.text)
    try:
        class Converter:
            def __init__(self):
                self.usd = currency[0]
                self.eur = currency[1]
                self.rub = sum

            def dollar(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.usd))

            def euro(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.eur))

        def extract_arg(arg):
            return arg.split()[1:]

        answer = extract_arg(message.text)
        sum = int(answer[0])
        converter = Converter()
        sum1 = round(converter.dollar(), 2)
        sum2 = round(converter.euro(), 2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'USD: {sum1}\nEUR: {sum2}')
    except IndexError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сумму после команды')
```

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, можно заменить `,` на `.` и будет работать. Так вот работает:

```
float('77,59'.replace(',','.'))
```

Ну, то есть у вас будет видимо:

```
int(float(self.usd.replace(',','.')))
```

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, во-первых - это не копия вашего ответа. Во-вторых, я считаю, что этот ответ лучше, т.к. содержит только самую суть, и есть пояснение.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Если бы ты посмотрел сразу на наши ответы, то увидел бы, что я дал ответ на полминуты раньше :)  Сначала по сути, а потом дополнил примером. И только после этого уже я увидел твой ответ. Причём, без пояснений - что ты сделал с кодом. Надо всё же пояснять. Добавишь пояснение - с удовольствием поставлю плюс. Я всегда плюсую чужие ответы, когда они хорошие.

Comment: я тоже плюсую...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1192910/revisions

Answer (score 3):

Надо заменить `,` на `.` т.к. питон использует `.` для `float`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['convert'])
def cmd_convert(message):
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    currency = []
    for figures in soup.select('span.inline-stocks__value_inner'):
        currency.append(figures.text)
    try:
        class Converter:
            def __init__(self):
                self.usd = currency[0]
                self.eur = currency[1]
                self.rub = sum

            def dollar(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.usd.replace(',', '.')))

            def euro(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.eur.replace(',', '.')))

        def extract_arg(arg):
            return arg.split()[1:]

        answer = extract_arg(message.text)
        sum = int(answer[0])
        converter = Converter()
        sum1 = round(converter.dollar(), 2)
        sum2 = round(converter.euro(), 2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'USD: {sum1}\nEUR: {sum2}')
    except IndexError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сумму после команды')
```